Any easy way to modify bottom of vanity to seal off opening?
Is there an easy way to modify this vanity so that it’s sealed to the floor? Or would I be better off buying a new vanity that has it already?

would I be better off? ... that is entirely your decision to make

why don't you askhow to modify the vanity? ... all the questions you are asking are yes/no questions that have a yes answer

When you stand at the vanity, are your toes underneath the lower bar?

Can you provide a magnifying glass with your photo?

Generally a flat panel is cut to fit the opening and attached to the front legs of the cabinet using things that look like broom clips, but are actually manufactured for the purpose..
search "plinth panel clip" and "cabinet leg clip" for some examples.
If you can't get the right clips you could zip tie some wood to the legs and then glue or screw the kick panel to that. (cut a groove for the zip tie to hide in)
